# Is there any way to retrieve another plugin's config in a kong plugin?

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I'm a bit new to *[Kong](https://konghq.com/)*. By now, I have two plugins (let's call them `A` and `B`) which both of them get a config table in their `access` function. As far as I know, *Kong* itself will fill this table based on the plugin's schema.

My problem is that I need some fields of `A`'s config in `B` and I couldn't find a way to solve this issue.

```lua
-- plugin A's access function
function A:access(config)
 -- I have access to A's config in here
end
```

```lua
-- plugin B's access function
function B:access(config)
 -- I need to access to A's config in here
end
```

Ofcourse, a trivial solution would be to add the needed fields in both plugins which is not efficient, since it will leads to code duplication.

Comment: Short answer you cannot.
Plugins can be instantiated several time with different configs.
Not sure why you say code duplication, you can share code between your plugins, and in lua or yaml you can reference parameters to no duplicate values.
Another solution can be to have plugin A putting info into the message header and plugin B getting it

Comment: First, thanks for your response. Second, I got your point that we can use the same value for both config schemas' default values. But, I need to share the actual passed value in the runtime so that I don't have to change a single value in both locations.

Also, by now I use the second solution you've mentioned (putting the message in the request's header). But, the thing is that I also use a dynamic key for that header which is set in the plugin's config and therefore I need to know the rendered config of the past plugin.

Comment: For me you have a design issue, you are hardly coupling 2 things, merge your plugins and voilà

Comment: Actually, you're right somehow as a plugin should be independent. But, in my case, I don't know how to decouple them as I use them as middleware. More precisely, first, a plugin will extract the claims (phone, etc.) from the sent JWT token and set them in the response header, and in other plugins will try to read that header. Therefore, I need to know the header key in both plugins.